# Gparted issue with Windows partitions (unable to read content) - dual-boot win7 ubuntu16.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, gparted

I have a dual-boot win7 and ubuntu 16.04 and wanted to shrink my windows partition. But when opening Gparted all the partitions are there but Gparted can't tell how much is used on my OSDISK (so can't resize). Plus i just noticed it makes them disapear from the sidebar in Files. Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Gparted can't resize an NTFS file system in various situations including when the file system wasn't closed by windows properly or if you haven't installed support for it. It disapears from the side bar because it automatically unmounts file systems being worked on.

Comment: what support would I need to install?

Comment: Do you run GParted on your Ubuntu install or via live OS?

Comment: Was running from a live OS. I finally removed Windows entirely. I accepted the answer since it is a good advice, the exact answer from my question came from the above comments from jdwolf. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gparted isn't the best tool for managing NTFS partitions. Instead, you should boot to windows and use Disk Management on Windows to resize the partition. Here's [a guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/) for how to do it.

1. Go to the control panel and search "partition".

[image]

2. Click "Create and format hard disk partitions"

[image]

3. Right click the partition you want to shrink and click "Shrink
   Volume". Follow through the dialogs.

Comment: Thanks, i take the advice but still want to solve the issue of GParted unable to read correctly the OSDISK and causing it to disappear.